# Eisenbud-Harris, Geometry of Schemes, I.3.3 (prime ideal sheaf)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ a quasi-coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_S$-algebras. Let $X$ be the set of all prime ideal sheafs of $S$ in $\mathcal{F}$. Then Eisenbud-Harris define a set-theoretic map $f: X \rightarrow S$ by taking a prime ideal sheaf $\mathscr{P} \in X$ to "its inverse image under the morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_S \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$." Can someone please spell the details of this map? In particular, why is it well-defined? I can see that if $U_1$ is an affine open of $S$, and $\mathscr{P}(U_1)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal{F}(U_1)$ (and not the unit ideal), then contracting $\mathscr{P}(U_1)$ to $\mathcal{O}_S(U_1)$ under the ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_S(U_1) \rightarrow \mathcal{F}(U_1)$ gives a point of $S$ in $U_1$. But what if there is another affine open $U_2$ of $S$ such that $U_1 \cap U_1 = \emptyset$ and $\mathscr{P}(U_2)$ is also a prime ideal?